# appendTo still linking to original container function

Tags: jquery, html

I have to container divs. The one contains a set of dynamic divs the user can select from. When an item is clicked it is append to the second div container. What is happening is that it is still seeing the first container divs function to appendto.

html markup.
removed brackets to show.

```
<div id="orders">   
  <div class="order" id="1"> 1 </div>
  <div class="order" id="2"> 2 </div>
  <div class="order" id="3"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

jquery markup.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#droplist").sortable();

    $(".order").on('click',function(){
        alert('clicked');
        $(this).removeClass('order');
        $(this).addClass('drop');
        $(this).appendTo('#droplist');
    });
});
```

My question is why is it still seeing the calling function when i have removed the class and put in another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because the click event was attached to the element. Once the event has been attached, it must be removed from the element. While order may be the class that the selector used for applying the event handler, all jquery really say was an array of elements to use.

Note that the event handler is only attached one time here as well. Any future order classed elements would not have this event handler.

There are a few ways to remedy this. You could remove the click event once clicked.

http://jsbin.com/menaloxu/1/edit

```
$(".order").on('click',function(){
    alert('clicked');
    $(this).removeClass('order');
    $(this).addClass('drop');
    $(this).appendTo('#droplist');
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

Or you could delegate the click event to only the order elements

http://jsbin.com/kasipexe/1/edit

```
$("body").on('click',".order",function(){
    alert('clicked');
    $(this).removeClass('order');
    $(this).addClass('drop');
    $(this).appendTo('#droplist');
});
```

Comment: beautiful thank you, this would work for a panel containing these divs as well, i take it